# Derivative of a set of equations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am a new learner of Mathematica, I think this question should be simple, but I just can't get the correct answer...

This is my equations:

```
p=x+y
q=2x+y
r=p+q
```

And I want to get the derivation of r by x, so the answer should be 3 [r=(x+y)+(2x+y)=3x+y]

But the output I got is a+b ??!!  Why?

[image]

Comment: You appear to have some old definitions laying around, `Clear[x, y, p, q, r]` or `Clear["Global`*"]` then try again. Although you need to `Set` the values of `p`  and `q`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[p, q, r, x, y]
p = x + y;
q = 2 x + y;
r = p + q
```

> 3 x + 2 y

```
D[r, x]
```

> 3

Or:

```
Clear[p, q, r, x, y]
r[x_, y_] := (p = x + y; q = 2 x + y; p + q)
D[r[x, y], x]
```

> 3

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But for "D[r[x,y],x]", the output I got is "{False,False,0} " instead of 3. Do you know what happened?

Comment: @Joanne, it might be an issue with `Set` (`=`) vs. `Equal` (`==`). `Set` is for setting a variable; `Equal` will test if the lhs and rhs are equal, and return True or False.